# unable to show user menu when logged in

Tags: wordpress

I am using the following code to logged in

```
 $username = "demo";

         if($user=get_user_by('login',$username)){
            print_r($user);

                 clean_user_cache($user->ID);

                 wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                 wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
                 wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID , true, false);

                  update_user_caches($user);
            }
        echo is_user_logged_in();
```

When I am printing the value of `is_user_logged_in()` then is is 1 but if it is logged in then I should show the different menu in wordpress. How can I achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your question is a bit hard to understand. If you just trying to display a menu based on if the user is logged in or not you can make easy checks like:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  // show the menu for logged users
} else {
  // show the menu when the user is not logged.
}
```